# getSupportActionBar() returns null with Robolectric

Tags: android, android-actionbar, junit4, robolectric, android-support-library

The method getSupportActionBar() returns null when i invoke it through a Test Case based in Roboelectric and JUnit.

This is my simple test case:

```
package com.mobile.test;

import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.equalTo;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.robolectric.Robolectric;
import org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import com.mobile.android.core.R;
import com.mobile.android.core.activity.MainActivity;
import com.mobile.android.core.activity.TestActivity;

@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class NavigationDrawerTest {
private Activity activity;

@Test
public void testNavigationDrawer() {
    activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(MainActivity.class).create().get();
    String hello = activity.getResources().getString(R.string.drawer_open);
    System.out.println(hello);
    assertEquals(hello, "Menu");
}
}
```

And this is my Activity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
// Drawer related
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
String[] mDrawerOptions;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav-drawer
    if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    }
}
}
```

Any bright ideas on hwo to fix this??
DO i have to write some shadow activity or does anyone knows how to work with these action bar problems with RObolectric??

Thanks for any help

Comment: Should be fixed in robolectric 2.2 => http://robolectric.blogspot.be/2013/10/robolectric-22-released.html

Answer (score 5):

**Support ActionBar**
I was able to get back an instance of the Support ActionBar by adding a @Config annotation to my test with the Gingerbread sdk build number:

```
@Test @Config(reportSdk = 10)
public void actionbarTest(){
.... Your Test here
}
```

A simple project setup can be seen here: [simple-robolectric](https://github.com/marsucsb/simple-robolectric)

**ActionBarSherlock**
You have to add modified ActionBarSherlock files to your test package and call the following methods in your @Before method:

```
ActionBarSherlock.registerImplementation(ActionBarSherlockRobolectric.class);
ActionBarSherlock.unregisterImplementation(ActionBarSherlockNative.class);
ActionBarSherlock.unregisterImplementation(ActionBarSherlockCompat.class);
```

The full set of instructions can be found here: [ActionBar and Robolectric working together](https://gist.github.com/marsucsb/6059760)

**Update**
With Robolectric 2.2 you only have to add the config annotation "@Config(reportSdk = 10)" to your test methods or class and it should work as well.

Comment: Hi Marco, thanks for your reply but I am not using ActionBarSherlock. 
I am using the android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity. Do you have any ideas about that ?

Comment: sorry about that, I have modified the answer for your question.

Comment: Hello Marco, thanks again for your reply.
Now i am getting a very strange long error. It seems to come on inflating the layout for the MainActivity.

Comment: android.view.InflateException: XML file .\..\..\..\..\..\..\android-sdk-x86_64\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\layout\abc_action_bar_decor_include.xml line #-1 (sorry, not yet implemented): Error inflating class android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:805)

Comment: I had previously tried using a Shadow configuration using:                      @Config(shadows = {ShadowActionbarActivity.class})            and implementing a shadow class for ActionBarActivity that always returns some actionbar in the call to getSupportActionBar() but that was also failing

Comment: I have also included a project link in the answer to show my project setup.