# NullPointerException on getSupportActionBar() using Robolectric 2.3-SNAPSHOT

Tags: android, robolectric, android-gradle-plugin, android-actionbar-compat

im stuck to get robolectric up and running on my android project. I already have some long journey made to get to this point. Robolectric runs already a couple of my tests, but when i create some Activity which setup the ActionBar the Tests fails with an NullPointerException:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarImplICS.setNavigationMode(ActionBarImplICS.java:214)
    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarImplJB.setNavigationMode(ActionBarImplJB.java:20)
    at org.project.android.SearchLocationFilterActivity.setupActionBar(SearchLocationFilterActivity.java:57)
    at org.project.android.BaseFragmentActivity.onCreate(BaseFragmentActivity.java:67)
    at org.project.android.SearchLocationFilterActivity.onCreate(SearchLocationFilterActivity.java:22)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
    at org.fest.reflect.method.Invoker.invoke(Invoker.java:112)
    at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController$1.run(ActivityController.java:150)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLooper.runPaused(ShadowLooper.java:265)
    at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.create(ActivityController.java:147)
    at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.create(ActivityController.java:157)
```

In that Activity i setup the ActionBar, this code gets invoked.

```
@Override
protected void setupActionBar(final ActionBar actionBar)
{
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
    setSupportProgressBarVisibility(false);

}
```

I seen some post around this issue but can't figure out how solve this.

As im using some Base Activity the onCreate gets called from the extending Activitys onCreate() Method.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setupActionBar(getSupportActionBar());

}
```

My build.gradle uses the lastest SNAPSHOT to get me to this point:

```
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.0+'
 compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'

 testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.3-SNAPSHOT'
```

The Nullpointer raises in first line, so ActionBar is **null** when i pass it to the Method.

Anyone got this working ?

UPDATE:

Found this [Pull](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/724) Request which seem to solve this problem but looks really hacky to me. The Problem is even more discussed in [this thread](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/pull/659).

Comment: on which line exactly does it fail.

Comment: show whole activity code

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a snapshot of Robolectric 2.3 and I also hit a NPE until I started setting the 'reportSDK' property. I first used the `@Config` annotation like this:

```
@Test
@Config(reportSDK = 13)
public void myTest() { 
    // test here
}
```

If this does fix the problem, I'd recommend using a properties file to apply this configuration. Since the `@Config` annotation is not inherited, setting this value in a file is the best way to apply it to all tests, including new ones added in the future.

The properties file must be named `org.robolectric.Config.properties` and should contain this:

```
reportSdk=13
```

This properties file must be accessible on your classpath.

I originally tried this solution thanks to this SO question: [getSupportActionBar() returns null with Robolectric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17993239/getsupportactionbar-returns-null-with-robolectric)

Comment: I already use an org.robolectric.Config.properties file, i need this to get around the "API Level 19 is not supported" Error. But it does not solve the NPE Problem to me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to create a custom theme as shown [Here](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/724#issuecomment-27268239). that fixed the NPE for me ( although I've other problems with the ActionBar - see [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21264849/android-content-res-resourcesnotfoundexception-in-robolectric-2-2/21310177?noredirect=1#comment32154183_21310177) for details - )